# Automatically refresh calendar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a calendar event with PHP.

I need if user post about event on the date, the other user can see the change directly without click refresh button. How I do that ? with ajax, jquery or what ?

Here's the code

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
$monthNames = Array(
   "January",
   "February",
   "March",
   "April",
   "May",
   "June",
   "July",
   "August",
   "September",
   "October",
   "November",
   "December"
);

if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"]))
    $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) 
    $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");


$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];
$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;
if ($prev_month == 0)
{
   $prev_month = 12;
   $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
if ($next_month == 13) 
{
   $next_month = 1;
   $next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?>
<table width="200">
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left"><a href="<?php 
  echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; 
?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Previous</a></td>
<td width="50%" align="right"><a href="<?php 
  echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; 
?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a></td>

</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong><?php 
echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear;
 ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>S</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>M</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>T</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>W</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>T</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>F</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>S</strong></td>
</tr>
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) 
{
     if(($i % 7) == 0 )
     {
         echo "";
     }
     if($i < $startday)
     {
        echo "<td></td>\n";
     }else 
     {
        $sql = "select * from data_agenda where date='".($i - $startday + 1).'-'.$cMonth.'-'.$cYear."'";
        $hs = mysql_query($sql);
        $event = mysql_num_rows($hs);
        echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'".($event > 0 ? " bgcolor='yellow'" : '').">";
       echo "<a href=2.php?tgl=".urlencode($i - $startday + 1)."&month=".urlencode($monthNames[$cMonth-1])." onclick=\"window.open(this.href,'window','width=640,height=480,resizable,scrollbars,toolbar,menubar') ;return false;\">".($i - $startday + 1)."</a><br>";
        echo "</td>\n";
     }
     if(($i % 7) == 6 )
     {
         echo "</tr>\n";
     }
}
```

Need your help please...

Thanks before,

Comment: Indentation is a good thing.

Comment: what identation do you mean ?

Comment: Code indentation, it makes code easier to read.

Comment: @vascowhite Do you mean line identation ? I've done that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the HTTP Protocol itself is not able to realize that. User B does his request and get the response from the server. Now the communication between client and server is finished until the User does another request. If you want to notify the user about changes on the current site which is shown in the browser then you need a realtime technology.

One option is to ask the server for example every 10 seconds if something has changed with an asyncron xml request (ajax) and then modify the DOM of the clients browser with javascript. This is not a very good solution because if you have many clients and each of them asks the server every 10 seconds you will get a lot of traffic.

The better option ist to open a socket from the client to the server that means you are permanently connected to the server and the server is able to notify the client that something has changed.

You need something like nodejs (http://nodejs.org/) to be able to notify the other clients from your server side. Nodejs is a server-side javascript implementation you can use to open a port on your server, listening for socket-connections from your clients.

socket.io (http://socket.io/) is another thing you like to check out. Socket.io is able to handle older browsers where a js socket is not available like IE 9.

Another option (if you dont like to use server-side javascript) is ratchet a php implementation of a socket-server, it has a good documentation and some examples to show you how it works. I have made good experiences with ratchet (http://socketo.me/), especially this example is really nice and should be what you are looking for:

http://socketo.me/docs/push

Please realize that this is not done in 3 Minutes. If you never used sockets before it will take some time to understand and integrate it to your project. But if it is finished it is a really nice thing. Please take notice that this is only possible with newer browsers which are able to open a HTML5 Websocket.

Comment: Can you describe more ? I'm still confused about your answer, Thank you...

Comment: Hi All,

The case now is I have 2 user. User A and user B. User A make an appointment on that calendar but user B isn't. When user A finish it, user B must see the changes without click refresh button.

That is what I need your help...